# Cast en postgres operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

Saludos, 
me encuentro realizando una consulta SQL. La columna a la que le aplico la condición WHERE es de tipo character varying, pero el dato con el que completo la condición es un entero.

```
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = 123
```

Obteniendo el siguiente mensaje:

```
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Se que debo hacer un casteo en el 123 para que se tome como character varying.
Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?
gracias

Comment: Solo añadelo así 
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = '123'

Comment: @Ajeno: Aunque la pregunta fue muy sencilla, creo que sería bueno que pongas tu comentario como respuesta.

Comment: @sstan Gracias ya lo hice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando escribes

```
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = 123
```

Lo que estás haciendo no está claro. Se puede interpretar de dos maneras:

```
to_number(codigo) = 123
```

o

```
codigo = '123'
```

el primer caso haría que son iguales '0123' y '123' y '123.0'. Es por eso que hay que ser explicito. Otras formas de escribirlo son:

```
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo::integer = 123
```

o

```
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = 123::text
```

Comment: Hola, como mencione en el titulo de la pregunta, aparece el mensaje "operator does not exist: character varying = integer".

Comment: Exacto. No se puede comparar texto con enteros porque no está claro qué signifca. Entonces para evitar errores Postgresql no lo permite hacer. Tienes que elegir a qué nivel quieres la igualdad ¿consideras `"123.0" = "123"`? si la respuesta es sí usa `codigo::integer = 123`, si la respuesta es no usa `codigo = 123::text`

Comment: como el tipo de dato de la tabla es un character varying, me parece mejor usar   codigo = 123::text. Aunque codigo = '123'  es útil,  me parece mas versátil la anterior de la otra forma. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Solo añádelo así

```
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = '123'
```

Comment: Hola. Si funciona, pero, existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: @chenio: para que quieres otra forma de hacerlo, si esta es la forma mas sencilla? Hay algo que no has mencionado en tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola, pregunto por tener otras formas de hacerlo, puede que para esta pregunta sirva, pero para otros casos, conocer de otras opciones puede ser útil.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que desea es hacer un [formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) de su valor , podría usar [to_char()](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/to_char.php) que recibe dos parametros el valor `int` y una `mascara` de formato (por ejemplo para 3 caracteres sin ceros a la izquierda '999')

```
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = to_char(123,'999');
/* o cast directamente */
SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = 123::text
```

> Tomando en consideración enviarle al query deseado siempre el tipo de valor que especifica en la tabla de su base de datos , si es cadena enviarle cadena y no un Entero `SELECT * FROM tablaCodigo WHERE codigo = '123'`

Comment: Hola, el segundo parámetro de la función  to_char, que otra mascara puede servir para este ejemplo?  gracias

Comment: Para un campo entero, sería esa teniendo en consideración la cantidad de dígitos con la que fue creada en la base de datos. estos valores están en la documentación que proporcione . https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/to_char.php